# Facebook's URL previewing technique in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am very new to asp.net and I have got a task in which I have to generate preview of an URL exactly the same way facebook does. I read an [article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/07/26/How-are-Facebook-and-Google-creating-link-previews) which helped me to understand the basics of URL preview like facebook.
I also used [HTML AGILITY PACK](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) from which I was able to fetch the TITLE & DESCRIPTION of an URL.

But I am unable to generate image thumbnails the way facebook does.
Can anyone please help me in getting this done. I am developing this application in C#.

Comment: i can say that facebook does crawl the images at the url and shows you them urls. So you need to extract img tags in the document and show them as thumbnails. This requires some image processing.